# How to add condition to IN method

Tags: sql

I am working in some custom technology for my company, and I have to create a query with 'IN' clause, but I can only send a dynamic parameter to query, and I can not manipulate the query in any other way (for example concatenate query string before)

What I am trying to achieve is to filter a list of values (with 'IN' clause). List of values for 'IN' are all in the external parameter that can be null or some list of values.

Here is a simplified query:

```sql
select * from TABLE where COLUMN1='something' 
and COLUMN2 in ({dynamic_paramater})
```

I want to filter values when {dynamic_paramater} is not null, and to list all values (like the 'IN' clause don't exist at all in query) if that parameter is null.

I would like to do something like this (obviously the syntax is wrong)

```sql
select * from TABLE where COLUMN1='something' 
if {dynamic_paramater} is not null then 
and COLUMN2 in ({dynamic_paramater})
```

Comment: Tag appropriate database name with the question.

Comment: Please include a sample query without using placeholders.  Note that binding dynamic values to a `WHERE IN` clause is generally difficult.

Comment: You are trying to do with ORMs. then mention which ORM you are using like ibatis, Torque , Hibernate etc. We have a different ways to do in different ORMs.

Comment: We are using Microsoft SQL (not mySQL) I don't know what version is on our server. As for ORM, I mentioned that it is our custom technology used only in eFront company. It's called Front Script, but I doubt it means anything to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE COLUMN1='something' 
AND ({dynamic_parameter} IS NULL OR COLUMN in ({dynamic_parameter}) );
```

But you must give exact `NULL` to `{dynamic_parameter}` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below by using `coalesce()`

```
   select * from TABLE where COLUMN1='something' 
    and  (COLUMN2 in ( coalesce(dynamic_paramater,-99999))
```

in case of null dynamic_paramater set a value which is always false thoug i fixed it -99999 -- i guess -99999 will not be in your column2 ever

thoug you have not any information in your quesion if 1st condition is true and 2nd is false then what will happen if you need data then need or condition

```
    select * from TABLE where COLUMN1='something' 
    or  (COLUMN2 in ( coalesce(dynamic_paramater,-99999))
```